# My word finder not working: do-while Loop problem

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to make a word finder but it shows error in the do while loop.
Maybe there's a problem with the exec() function.
here's my JavaScript:

```js
const words = [/lorem/gi, /ipsum/gi];

const body = document.body;

let log = [];

for (const w of words) {
  let yes = true;

  let theWord = w.exec(String(body.innerHTML));
  loo: do {
    console.log(theWord == null);
    if (theWord == null) {
      yes = false;
      console.log(yes);
      break loo;
    } else {
      log.push(theWord);
    }
  } while (yes == true);
}

console.log(log);
```

i'll do the styling on the page later using index and span;
but for now, please help me with this

html:

```
<body>

    <h1>Ipsum Lorem</h1>
    <h1>lorem Ipsum</h1>
    <h1>Lorem ipsum</h1>
    <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
    <h1>LoRem iPsUm lOrEm Lorem</h1>

    <span style="display: block;">lorem ipsum</span>

    <br>

    <b style="display: block;">LoReM iPsUm</b>

    <br>

    <i style="display: block;">lOrEm IpSuM</i>

    <br>

    <a href="#">ipSUM LORem</a>

    <br>
    <br>

    lorem IPSUM

    <br>
    <br>

        <div>
            LOREM ipsum
        </div>

<style>
    body {
        background-color: #444;
        color: #fff;
    }
</style>

</body>
```

I edited the question as one asked to show the html.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: The non-stopping loop

Comment: I think you can add also the text in the html <body> so we can see the unstopping loop

Comment: The loop runs while `yes` is true. `yes` only changes based on the value of `theWord`. `theWord` never changes within the loop. How is the loop supposed to stop?

Comment: Looks like, if a word is found on the page, it'll keep pushing this word to `log` forever.

Comment: I tried now, and yes you are right, is keep console.logging false

Comment: @Biffen: yeah, not sure what that do/while loop is even there for. Is it an attempt to deal with late loading of content? Looks suspicious.

Comment: The do-while loop is to find every word in the HTML using the exec() function to go through all the words

Comment: A very, very, very! Thanks to Biffen and trincot for making me realize my mistake

Comment: My answer is solved, i just had to put theWord variable in the do-while loop.
It was a silly mistake

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you never change `theWord` *inside* the loop. So if `theWord` is not `null` in the first iteration, it also will not be in the second or any other iteration of the loop: so the loop will hang.

You need to assign to `theWord` the result of `exec` *inside* the loop.

Just by moving that line into the loop, the code works:

```js
const words = [/lorem/gi, /ipsum/gi];

const body = document.body;

let log = [];

for (const w of words) {
  let yes = true;
  loo: do {
    let theWord = w.exec(String(body.innerHTML));
    console.log(theWord == null);
    if (theWord == null) {
      yes = false;
      console.log(yes);
      break loo;
    } else {
      log.push(theWord);
    }
  } while (yes == true);
}

console.log(log);
```

There is much to comment on this code, such as:

- Don't do `yes == true` when `yes` is a boolean. Just test the boolean
- Don't introduce another variable like `yes`, when the loop condition is simply `theWord` being not `null`.
- When the `while` condition is evaluated, it will always be true, since otherwise the `break` had been executed. So this could be just `do ... while(true)`.
- To collect all matches it is not needed to use `.exec`. There is the string `.match` method (which takes a regex as argument), that does this collecting for you out of the box.